# Is it possible to define function that allows invalid input in Python

Tags: python, function, object, variables

I have defined a function that checks if my statement is valid and assigns it to a variable which is being fed as a string, because before assignment this variable does not exist yet. The function is as follows:

```
#Check if item is in HTML otherwise appoint NOT FOUND
def try_except(try_statement, variable):
    try:
        locals()[variable]=try_statement
    except:
        locals()[variable]="NOT_FOUND"
    return(locals()[variable])
```

This function works fine *but only* if the input try statement yield a valid outcome, which defeats the entire purpose of the designed function.

For example, the following statement fails:

```
SHIPPING=try_except(i.find("span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}).text, "SHIPPING")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-641-adff14bb2f4b> in <module>
----> 1 SHIPPING=try_except(i.find("span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}).text, "SHIPPING")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Whereas the concept outside of the designed function works perfectly:

```
try:
    locals()["SHIPPING"]=i.find("span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}).text
except:
    locals()["SHIPPING"]="NOT_FOUND"
    print(locals()["SHIPPING"])

prints: NOT_FOUND
```

Is there any way to define a function which does not validate the input statement and just proceeds with it as requested?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to do? I think that might exist a better way than using locals()

Comment: I am scraping items from multiple webpages, and need to keep uniform format for output. Sometimes elements from an item are not present, and errors occur. I could add try except for every item but it confuscates the code a lot and looks ugly, therefore I prefer a oneliner to do so, and then I ran into this problem

Comment: This all smells like a very convoluted way of doing something probably not so complicated. Don't modify `locals()`, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) explicitely says not to. Anyway, in your function, you could simply replace all the `locals()[variable] = ` by `dummy =` and nothing would change. If you are trying to automatically create variables by names, well, don't. Use a dict instead.

Comment: The point is: your code is failing exactly before entering the function, so what are you doing is not what you think. You try to access the "text" attribute (of None in that case) BEFORE entering the function. So your try_except function is doing nothing.

Comment: I had noticed, perhaps I just have to accept this it not going to work, and find another solution :)

Comment: If you're always going to use the `find` method on some object with 2 arguments like `"span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}`, you might want to create a function that takes the object and the arguments for find as parameters, and returns either the data it found or your default text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: don't do the thing with `locals()`.  It's completely unnecessary, since your function is returning the value (or at least trying to), and the caller is assigning it to the named variable *anyway*.  This is orthogonal to your `try/except` problem anyway so I'll say no more about it, other than to suggest that if in the future you ever feel the need to do something like this with `locals()` or `globals()`, *you should almost definitely not do that thing*.

The reason your function isn't working is that you're executing the code that raises the exception *before* you call the function, and therefore *outside* its try block.  Your `try_except` function needs to take *another function* as its parameter, so that it can call it *inside* its try block:

```
def try_except(func):
    """Return result of calling func, or "NOT FOUND"."""
    try:
        return func()
    except:
        return "NOT FOUND"
```

and then call it like:

```
SHIPPING = try_except(lambda: i.find("span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}).text)
```

Note that the `lambda` expression produces a function of zero arguments that will execute and return `i.find("span", {"id":"item-shipping-price-1"}).text` *when it is called*.  By passing this function into `try_except`, you allow it to execute that code within the `try` block and handle the exception by returning its default `"NOT FOUND"` value.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed how it should be done .